# How to add text before posts

Tags: php, customization, text

This is the picture of my site.[image: My site]

I have "show last posts on static page" option. So I can't edit this page in page editor. But I want to add text before getting posts. How do I do this?

I think just editing `index.php` with scrappy `<h1>Hello I am blah-blah</h1>` is a scrappiest way to do this. Help me, please.

Comment: Do you want to add text only on frontpage?

Comment: Yes, only on front page. Like "hello i am blahblah this is my site about blahblah" for people who just came and for better seo ranking.

Comment: Is it your theme? Or you've downloaded from repo and want to update in the future?

Comment: I've downloaded it for free and made a ton of customizing by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you are using [shamrock](https://wordpress.org/themes/shamrock/) theme.
To add the desirable header you can insert in header.php right after  tag following code:

```
<?php if(is_frontpage()) : ?>
<div class="head-title">
    <p class="about-me">your text</p>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Please, note, that if you want to get updates your theme, you should create child wordpress theme with custom header.php file

Comment: Thank you so much! That's what I needed. I've already made child theme.